# Two locations of gacutil.exe

Tags: gacutil

I'm developing on Windows 2008 R2 Server, 64 bit.
I'm learning how to use gacutil.exe
I found two copies of this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\
```

I built a dll in VS2007, then I added a build post event, that calls gacutil.exe to transfer the dll to GAC.
Does it matter which gacutil.exe I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume that you should use the file located at

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64
```

since it is the 64bit version of the utility and you are developing on a 64bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

IS there VS2007? I think you meant VS2008. You can use either of the gacutil based on the assembly you build on Visual studio. Is your assembly 64 bit. Check that in visual studio Biild-Configuration Manager. If you build a debug version see the active solution platform is that x86/x64? Use the appropriate gacutil then.